# How to validate a Text with Jface Dialog?

Tags: java, validation, text, dialog, jface

i created a Dialog with two input fields with the following Code.

```
 public class CCIDDialog extends TitleAreaDialog {

 private Text ccidText;
 private Text descriptionText;
 private String CCID;
 private String description;


 public CCIDDialog(Shell parentShell) {
  super(parentShell);
 }



public void create() {
    super.create();
    setTitle(_title);
    setMessage("Bitte geben Sie die CCID "+firstchar+"xxxxxxx und eine Beschreibung ein (max. 7-stellig): ", IMessageProvider.INFORMATION);   }



 @Override
  protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent) {
    Composite area = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(parent);
    Composite container = new Composite(area, SWT.NONE);
    container.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));
    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(2, false);
    container.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
    container.setLayout(layout);

    createCCID(container);
    createDescription(container);

    return area;
  }

  private void createCCID(Composite container) {
    Label lbtFirstName = new Label(container, SWT.NONE);
    lbtFirstName.setText("CCID (ohne "+firstchar+"): ");

    GridData dataCCID = new GridData();
    dataCCID.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
    dataCCID.horizontalAlignment = GridData.FILL;

    ccidText = new Text(container, SWT.BORDER);

    ccidText.setLayoutData(dataCCID);
  }

  private void createDescription(Composite container) {
    Label lbtLastName = new Label(container, SWT.NONE);
    lbtLastName.setText("Beschreibung: ");

    GridData dataDescription = new GridData();
    dataDescription.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
    dataDescription.horizontalAlignment = GridData.FILL;
    descriptionText = new Text(container, SWT.BORDER);
    descriptionText.setLayoutData(dataDescription);
  }



  @Override
  protected boolean isResizable() {
    return true;
  }

  // save content of the Text fields because they get disposed
  // as soon as the Dialog closes
  private void saveInput() {
      CCID = ccidText.getText();
      description = descriptionText.getText();

  }

  @Override
  protected void okPressed() {
    saveInput();
    super.okPressed();
  }

  public String getCCID() {
    return CCID;
  }

  public String getDescription() {
    return description;
  }
}
```

Is there a way to validate the ccidtext? 
If the user type more then 7 chars, he must get a notification and should not be able to continue the dialog. I read so lot at the internet but can`t find a solution for this problem.

Thank u so much for your help.

JonasInt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Text.addModifyListener` to add a `ModifyListener` which will be called each time the text is changed. You can also use `Text.addVerifyListener` to add `VerifyListener` which can actually prevent text being entered.

For `TitleAreaDialog` you can call `setMessage` or `setErrorMessage` to display a message in the title area.

You can disable the `OK` button on the dialog using:

```
getButton(IDialogConstants.OK_ID).setEnabled(false);
```

Note: `getButton(xxx)` can return `null` if you call it too early in the dialog construction. Buttons are created during the `createContents` method after the `createDialogArea` method has been called.

So you can access the buttons by overriding `createContents` like this:

```
@Override
protected Control createContents(final Composite parent)
{
  Control control = super.createContents(parent);

  // TODO access buttons here

  return control;
}
```

Comment: thanks :) .setTextLimit(8) directly work for the textfield :) is there a way to set the field that min 1 char must be entered ?

Comment: Where is the best place to call `getButton(IDialogConstants.OK_ID).setEnabled(false);` in order not to get back `null`?

Comment: @kerner1000 By overriding `createContents` - see updated answer

Comment: OK, thanks, I did it now in `create`, works as well. `createDialogArea` did not work. Now I see it, you already wrote it, im sorry!