# SWT Text allow to type only digits

Tags: java, swt

I want to allow in a SWT Text to type in only numbers.
I already know that I can do this with [How to set a Mask to a SWT Text to only allow Decimals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11831927/how-to-set-a-mask-to-a-swt-text-to-only-allow-decimals).

However the behavior there is not exactly what I want.

If I type in a non digit character it briefly appears in the Text field and than disappears. If I quickly type '123a' it will remove the whole '123a'.

What I want is to prevent the non digit char to appear at all in the Text. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a key down listener and stop the event for non-digit characters.

```java
text.addListener(SWT.KeyDown, event -> event.doit = Character.isDigit(event.character));
```

However that very simplistic code means that editing characters such as backspace and arrow keys will also be blocked. So you will need to check the `event.keyCode` for values to want to allow.

So maybe something like:

```java
text.addListener(SWT.KeyDown, event -> 
            event.doit = event.keyCode == SWT.BS || event.keyCode == SWT.DEL ||
            event.keyCode == SWT.ARROW_LEFT || event.keyCode == SWT.ARROW_RIGHT ||
            Character.isDigit(event.character));
```

Comment: Stopping the event KeyDown doesn't stop the typed char to appear in the Text field.

Comment: It does on macOS, so that must be a behaviour of the native control on your platform. Keydown is the earliest possible event so you are unlikely to be able to achieve this. I also agree with the other answer - stopping the user typing invalid characters is often considered a poor UI choice because the user may become frustrated.

Comment: It works for me, Win10

Answer (score 0):

The `VerifyListener` that intercepts the user input and has a `text` field that contains the entered text or is empty if some text was deleted.

Usually the `text` field will just contain the single char triggered by the current key stroke. When pasting text, however, the field contains the entire clipboard text.

The following snippet would prevent any text being inserted that contains non-digit chars.

```java
Text text = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
text.addVerifyListener(event -> {
  if (event.text contains a non-digit char) {
    event.doit = false;
  }
});
```

I didn't notice that unwanted characters 'slipped through' with this code.

Technically, you could event modify `event.text` to remove unwanted chars from the text. The `event.text` field as it is left by the listener will be applied.

From a usability point of view, the entire approach is questionable. Such a listener prevents users from pasting potentially invalid text, cleaning it up and then continue entering other data.

I'd suggest to show a validation error message in a suitable place near the digit-only input field and prevent the user from finishing data entry until the error is resolved (e.g. disable the OK/Save button in a dialog).

If you're already using JFace, you may want to take a look at the dialog validation classes:
[How to validate a Text with Jface Dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22224525/how-to-validate-a-text-with-jface-dialog)

Answer (score 0):

If you block all key presses other than digits, then the DELETE, BACKSPACE, and movement keys are also disabled. I use:

```
 private class TextKeyListener extends KeyAdapter
    {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed( KeyEvent e )
        {
            if (Character.isISOControl( e.character ))
                ;
            else if (!Character.isDigit( e.character ))
                e.doit = false;
        }
    }
```